# Use Autowire to get sftpChannel configured in spring xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am using the following spring configuration to transfer a file from local folder to remote SFTP server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp-2.2.xsd">

<bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="xxxxxxx" />
    <property name="knownHosts" value = "C:\knownhosts"/>
    <property name="user" value="wildfly" />
    <property name="password" value="w!ldfly" />
    <property name="port" value="22" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="sftpChannel" />

<sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="triggerFtpOutBound" channel="sftpChannel"
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" remote-directory="/home/wildfly">
</sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

I am using the following code to send file.

```
@Autowired
private MessageChannel sftpChannel;

Function()
{
   File f = new File("c:/test.txt");
   Message<File> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(f).build();
   sftpChannel.send(message);
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception at sftpChannel.send(message). How can i autowire sftpChannel in my code?

The following code works. But, i want to Autowire sftpChannel.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/config/spring-sftp.xml");
MessageChannel sftpChannel = context.getBean("sftpChannel", MessageChannel.class);

File f = new File("c:/test.txt");
Message<File> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(f).build();
sftpChannel.send(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use autowired you need to include

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

to your configuration file

```
<beans 
    //...
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    //...
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    //...

    <context:annotation-config />
    //...
</beans>
```

Here, there is a full example

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring works the same as any Spring application; the bean that gets the autowired channel must be declared as a bean in the context.

You can always debug Spring bean wiring by enabling DEBUG logging for `org.springframework`.

The framework puts out lots of information while wiring classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in your code, but that looks like you are going to use an `@Autowired` property from the **constructor**.

For this purpose you have to use the `constructor injection`.

Even if your `Function` is a valid Spring bean, it is a bad idea to send any message from the `constructor`.

Please, revise your design and read more books about Spring.